# Using operator/ for directories: good or bad idea?

Tags: c++, directory, operator-overloading

I have a `Directory` class that stores a string and has a `/` operator, so that `a / b` where `a` is a `Directory` and `b` is a `std::string` will add `"/"` and `b` to the string stored in `a`, like this:

```
Directory a("/home/joe/foo");
Directory b = a / "bar";
```

This will have `b` store the string `/home/joe/foo/bar`. Is this actually usable, or is it just unnecessary fanciness?

Comment: This isn't really a question, imho. If it works, it's usable...

Comment: If that would make your work (life!) easier then GO!

Comment: I wouldn't do that myself, as it doesn't really seem very readable to someone else. My thought process would be:
"Ok, I see there's a directory a. And a divided by "bar", what does that mean?" More appropriate would just be a method with a clear name.

Comment: You can do `operator+` instead for string concatenation too if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost Filesystem has overloaded operator/ in a similar fashion.  Before you get too far have you checked out boost filesystem?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: And it's a candidate for inclusion in the next iteration of the language standard.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know boost had that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea because you are changing the common meaning of the / operator.

Comment: How does this change the common meaning of `/` in paths? C++ has always interpreted operators in context. E.g. `+` for stings is not commutative, `a+b != b+a`

Comment: The statement b = a / "bar"; is constructing a path from 3 components, addition would make more sense here as well. Understanding a / "bar" requires a lot of contextual information that might not be available and is also platform(s) specific.

Comment: I don't see any place where contextual information wouldn't reasonably be available. Could you give an example?

Comment: @Gary: The problem with `+` is that it's unclear whether `path x = foo() + ".txt"` appends `".bar" or `"/.bar"`. There's no such ambiguity in `path x = foo() / ".bar"`. IOW, paths are lists of strings, and `/` adds an entire string.

Comment: You missed a backtick somewhere in there, @MSalters.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading operators in this style is... odd. I won't say that its terrible or bad, but you have to keep in mind that in most cases `operator/` is more like saying "divide this by that". Now, you're free to overload the operators to whatever you want, but the convention for strings (which can represent directories) is usually that you would overload something like `+` instead.

When I first come across this code, I get the strange feeling you're trying to divide a directory by something else. And that's just really confusing and not too clear. `+` might be a better choice, or just using an explicit method name like `Append` or `Combine`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea since it doesn't follow common sense.
In book , it offers the rules for operator overloading:
Don't Overload Operators with Built-in Meanings

Comment: In the case of file names, what does `/foo/bar.txt` mean?

Comment: All operators in C++ have a built-in meaning. You cannot in fact add completely new operators.

Comment: @Yakk: It means a file `bar.txt` in a folder `foo` in the root directory.

Comment: @JoeZeng: That was a rhetorical question. The point was that every developer already understands `/` as both division and a path separator, depending on context.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it was a response to the answer, not a request for clarification.